# Draw Canvas into a Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place a Canvas into a Drawable ... code below ... any help is appreciated!!

```
Drawable marker = makeMarker();
boundCenterBottom(marker);
item.setMarker(marker);

private Drawable makeMarker(){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(20);

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawText("Some Text", 100, 100, paint);

    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    return d;
}
```

Comment: It seems you draw text out of bitmap area. You have bitmap 100x100 and draw text at (100,100).

Comment: tried

    c.drawText("dd", 0, 0, paint);

still not working

Comment: Try (0, 50), this position baseline aligned, so (0,0) also out of area :) Also, I'm not sure, but you have to set width for Paint. And note that your bitmap transparent and your text is black, so choose correct background to see it.

Comment: bam and there it is ... thx dude. kinda new to android/java programming, next time .. will check my method params better. thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

getIntrinsicWidth() not works at event onCreate() and equals zero. So, nothing happined